# Unable to download the file from Node.js using the POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, export, http-post

I found a few questions related to the same but the answer didn't work for me so posting the same here.

I have some XML content which has been created programmatically and displayed in Textarea. I need an option to export or download the same to the local system. So I am using the `POST` request to send these data to `NODE.JS` where I am creating my `XML` file and trying to download it. I know if I am using the `GET` it would work directly but with `POST` it's failing. Is there a way I can do this?

Here is the code I have:

Angularjs POST request:
I have a button when clicked I am passing all the XML data to my NODE.js function:

```
$scope.ExportXML    =   function(XMLContent){
    var XMLContent  =   XMLContent;
    
    $http({
        url     :   "/ExportData",
        method  :   "POST",
        data    :   XMLContent
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Data Exported");
        window.location.assign(data);
        $window.open(data);
    }).error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('ERROR: could not download file');
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

My Node.js function which would create the XML file with the data:

```
const fs        =   require('fs');
const path      =   require('path');
const reqPath   =   path.join(__dirname, '../');

exports.exportfile      =   function(req,res)
{   
    var ContentData     =   req.body;
    var FileName        =   "XMLDATA.xml";  
    
    fs.appendFile(FileName, ContentData, function (err)
    {
        const FilePath = reqPath+FileName;
        res.download(FilePath);
    })
}
```

As you can see from the success function of the ANGULARJS I tried a couple of things but none worked. I tried sending back the path of the file using the `callback(FilePath);` and then I am trying to download the file using the `$window.open(data);` but I am getting the following error `Not allowed to load local resource:`.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching I was able to do it. Rather than sending the DATA to NODE.JS using the POST, I tried creating the file within my AngularjS function and downloaded it from there itself. if in case anyone is looking for the solution here it is:

```
//Export the contents of XML to text file
$scope.ExportXML    =   function(XMLContent){
    
    var filename = 'HelloWorld.xml'       
    var blob = new Blob([XMLContent], {type: "text/xml"});
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
    {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else
    {
        var e                   =   document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a                       =   document.createElement('a');
        a.download              =   filename;
        a.href                  =   window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.dataset.downloadurl   =   ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
        e.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}
```